# The request is giving me a 404 error, in my testing class in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

The issue is that I am testing a method, but it gives me a 404 error, I have already put my bearer token in my request, which is logical because I need to put the header with "authorization".
When I make this request in Postman it gives me good results. What am I failing at?

***MonedaServiceTest.java:***

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:config.properties")
@Sql("/data.sql")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MonedaServiceTest {

    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonedaRestController.class);
    @Autowired
    IMonedaService monedaService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testGetMonedaPorId() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        String response = mockMvc
                .perform(get("http://localhost:8080/CashLetterAPI/rest/moneda/findById" + "/{id}", 1).header(
                        "Authorization",
                        "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJzb2Z0dGVrSldUIiwic3ViIjoiZXhhbXBsZSIsImlhdCI6MTYxOTcwNTE0MiwiZXhwIjoxNjE5NzExMTQyfQ.e82DP4xfm-sPPHmxEv5tzGSwnAVCnQeP61DSSWtZZlM45wT7tFNQSMakjy_FptYBwrN28CFlpt1dDuT6u_mjVA"))
                .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value())) //here debugger stops
                .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        logger.info("response: " + response);
        // assertEquals(1L, monedaService.getMonedaPorId(1L).getId());

    }
```

***The output console:***

```
 MockHttpServletRequest:
          HTTP Method = GET
          Request URI = /CashLetterAPI/rest/moneda/findById/1
           Parameters = {}
              Headers = [Authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJzb2Z0dGVrSldUIiwic3ViIjoiZXhhbXBsZSIsImlhdCI6MTYxOTcwNTE0MiwiZXhwIjoxNjE5NzExMTQyfQ.e82DP4xfm-sPPHmxEv5tzGSwnAVCnQeP61DSSWtZZlM45wT7tFNQSMakjy_FptYBwrN28CFlpt1dDuT6u_mjVA"]
                 Body = null
        Session Attrs = {}
    
    Handler:
                 Type = null
    
  

    MockHttpServletResponse:
               Status = 404
        Error message = null
              Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
         Content type = null
```

Comment: This is illogical, because that would be `HTTP403`. Using a wrongful URL is a typo and not a valid question.

Comment: wrong? I tested in Postman the same url and it's working fine @MartinZeitler

Comment: Just a guess: your `mockMvc` doesn't know about the service to test so it didn't "deploy" it.

Comment: Mmm i don't know how to fix that! @Thomas , thanks for the advice

Comment: `404` literally means that `/CashLetterAPI/rest/moneda/findById/1` does not exist. And do me a favor and forget about Postman; as it creates nothing but misconceptions, which in most cases cannot be applied to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone needs it, you don't need to specify your "server.servlet.context-path" in the get (), you just put the @RequestMapping you put in the controller. So finally:

```
String response = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/rest/moneda/findById/{moneda_id}", 1L)
               ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you used the wrong http method (did you register your endpoint as GET?). Also, the URL might just be wrong (maybe also the port). If you were talking to the correct endpoint, you should have received another status code.

Comment: Yes , it's a Get method